# How to tint an UIImage in a UIAlertController

Tags: swift, ios8, ios9, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

How can I create an `UIAlertController` with a cancel button and three other buttons with an icon? I am supporting iOS 8 upwards.
Each entry should be tinted...

Comment: Please provide some code, you have already tried and edit it to the question.

Comment: I thought to have the question and the answer (with code) separate is more clear... Don't you think?

Answer (score 3):

I tried and searched a lot and finally found the answer. Here it is:

#### **Create the `UIAlertController` with icons:**

The important part is the addition of the icons with `action1.setValue(UIImage(named: "Icon1"), forKey: "image")`

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Test 1", style: .Default, handler: {
    [unowned self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Action 1")
})
action1.setValue(UIImage(named: "Icon1"), forKey: "image")

let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Test 2", style: .Default, handler: {
    [unowned self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Action 2")
})
action2.setValue(UIImage(named: "Icon2"), forKey: "image")

let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Test 3", style: .Default, handler: {
    [unowned self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Action 3")
})
action3.setValue(UIImage(named: "Icon3"), forKey: "image")

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

optionMenu.addAction(action1)
optionMenu.addAction(action2)
optionMenu.addAction(action3)
optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

This is what I got. Ok so far

[image: UIAlertController with cancel button and 3 entries with icon]

---

#### **Tinting the entries**

Then I tried to tint everything and I added the following line underneath the instantiation of `UIAlertController`:
    optionMenu.view.tintColor = Colors.getColors().primaryTintColor

This looked pretty good with iOS8, but as I tested the same code with iOS9 I was surprised (the localization difference is because of different settings in the simulators):

**iOS8**
[image: Tinted UIAlertController with iOS8]

**iOS9**
[image: Tinted UIAlertController with iOS9]

#### **The solution**

I took me quite a while but then I found the solution. 
You have to set the tint color **after** you present the `UIAlertController`.

This is the final code:

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: nil, preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Test 1", style: .Default, handler: {
    [unowned self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Action 1")
})
action1.setValue(UIImage(named: "Icon1"), forKey: "image")

let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Test 2", style: .Default, handler: {
    [unowned self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Action 2")
})
action2.setValue(UIImage(named: "Icon2"), forKey: "image")

let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Test 3", style: .Default, handler: {
    [unowned self] (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
    print("Action 3")
})
action3.setValue(UIImage(named: "Icon3"), forKey: "image")

let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .Cancel, handler: nil)

optionMenu.addAction(action1)
optionMenu.addAction(action2)
optionMenu.addAction(action3)
optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)

presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
optionMenu.view.tintColor = Colors.getColors().primaryTintColor
```

Comment: This is interesting but have you submitted an app to the App Store that does this? You're using undocumented API-- the `image` key.

Comment: Yes I did, Apple did not complain about this.